# Python removing substrings from strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove some substrings from a string in a csv file.

```
   import csv
   import string

   input_file = open('in.csv', 'r')
   output_file = open('out.csv', 'w')
   data = csv.reader(input_file)
   writer = csv.writer(output_file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)# dialect='excel')
   specials = ("i'm", "hello", "bye")

   for line in data:
     line = str(line)
     new_line = str.replace(line,specials,'')
     writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))

    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()
```

So for this example:

```
 hello. I'm obviously over the moon. If I am being honest I didn't think I'd get picked, so to get picked is obviously a big thing.  bye.
```

I'd want the output to be:

```
obviously over the moon. If I am being honest I didn't think I'd get picked, so to get picked is obviously a big thing.
```

This however only works when im searching for a single word. So that specials = "I'm" for example.  Do I need to add my words to a list or an array?

Comment: paste a snippet of your file

Comment: edited with example @letsc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't iterating through specials, since it's a tuple rather than a list, so it's only grabbing one of the values. Try this:

```
specials = ["i'm, "hello", "bye"]

for line in data:
     new_line = str(line)
         for word in specials:
              new_line = str.replace(new_line, word, '')
     writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))
```

Comment: Ah - forgot to change specials to a list rather than a tuple. See changed code above. You had specials as a tuple, so you couldn't access individual elements by iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're already splitting the input via the `csv.reader`, but then you're throwing away all that goodness by turning the split line back into a string.  It's best not to do this, but to keep working with the lists that are yielded from the csv reader.  So, it becomes something like this:

```
for row in data:
    new_row = []  # A place to hold the processed row data.

    # look at each field in the row.
    for field in row:

        # remove all the special words.
        new_field = field
        for s in specials:
            new_field = new_field.replace(s, '')

        # add the sanitized field to the new "processed" row.
        new_row.append(new_field)

    # after all fields are processed, write it with the csv writer.
    writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't do anything but add a row inbetween each row of the csv file